# Single developer-to-do-all SDLC activities -- How should I proceed further?

Tags: development-environment

Working at client (non-IT) place as a .net programmer (alone) and asked to develope a windows application. No project manager, no SRS, no technical people to lead..., etc.

Directly getting requirement from customer on-their-need basis. It keep changes and has lot of ambguity. As the client is not understaning need of freezing requirement, it becomes huge headache to deal with.  Has to do self document of requirement, coding, testing, bug-fixing and delivering build, educating users for application use by myself only. Reporing to a Boss, who is non-technical guy and always not understanding these problems.

Now it becomes, single developer-to-do-all SDLC activities.  How should I proceed with this work environment?

Comment: Leave the client on his own or ask for better working conditions. This is plain inhuman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by **making demands** on your environment, and on what is asked of you:
*Demand* that requirements and deadlines are fixed and agreed upon, in writing, before you write a single line of code.
*Demand* that you are given enough time for testing and bugfixing in the development cycle.
*Demand* that you are given time to setup source control, automatic builds etc (whatever you feel like you need for your development environment to promote effective work).
*Demand* that you are given time to write documentation, so that you can spend more time writing code and less time doing application demos.

Continue with **backing it up**:
Document and show your boss some statistics on how you use your time. If it turns out you use much less on actually writing code, maybe he'll consider giving some of the less programming-related tasks to some other member of the department.

And finally, remember that this **this is not the only company in the world:**
Robert L. Lead has a very good point in his [How to be a Programmer: A Short, Comprehensive and Personal Summary](http://samizdat.mines.edu/howto/HowToBeAProgrammer.html): under [Recognizing when to go home](http://samizdat.mines.edu/howto/HowToBeAProgrammer.html#id2791398), he simply states:

> **Quit if you have to.**

This might not be a very compelling option, but should it come to it, leave the company for the greener grass on the other side. Even telling your boss you're ready to quit if your working conditions don't improve might help you actually get what you want. I doubt that your company want to be left with a software product that suddenly can't be supported or updated, because their only developer quit.

Comment: Seems we were a bit on the same level ;-). Clear post! I like the document-your-current-time bit.

Comment: 'Quit if you have to.'  That's a great way to build a career.  Knuckle down and get on with it.

Comment: @High, I'm not sure if you're positive or negative to what I'm saying, but if the working conditions in this company are really the way the OP describe them, maybe this isn't such a good place to build a career...? Besides, since he's the only dev. on the team, and it seems there are no plans to hire more people, what is the likelihood of a promotion? Why would they promote someone they need in his current position?

Comment: High Perf. Mark:   I've got to agree with Tomas - he works in a non-IT company, with no technical peers.  How is this a good environment to learn other than the slow and hard way. Also, just because you're in a job doesn't mean that you're married to it. If it's not a fit, or one side is exploiting the other, it's fair enough to bail.  Your employer can boot you out if things don't work out, you can fire your employer as well.

Comment: @Tomas: sorry for the lack of clarity -- I am absolutely opposed to your suggestion.

Comment: @High: Would you care to elaborate on why?

Answer (score 3):

Count your blessings, I'd say. Usually all the people standing between the developers and the users are just getting in the way of making successful software.

I think it is a good idea to adopt some agile tooling to organize yourself, like a scrum whiteboard, and by defining sprint periods/iterations. That will allow to manage your boss's and users' expectations, and still give them control over what should get priority. Don't forget to schedule for SDLC tasks, so you can make them visible to your boss. You should feel free to consider agile tooling as a supermarket: take what you think is useful and keep the rest in mind for later consideration.

As far as requirements documentation is concerned, I'd keep it very high level. I would not mind skipping it altogether but I can imagine that it feels sloppy, and it is perhaps also a way to document your achievements.

Comment: +1 for suggesting agile/scrum. Using iteration/sprint based project planning is a great way to give the users the flexibility they need while creating an environment you can actually get work done.

I'd give you an extra vote if I could for suggesting shopping around and adopting what you need instead of dogmatically adopting a full agile methodology. Don't change anything if it doesn't solve a problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of **educating both your customer and boss**; and **an agile approach** could be helpful here. It depends on how this project is billed to the customer.

***If the customer is getting a fixed price deal***, yet is allowed to change the specs, then educate your boss (or whoever is accountable for the financial results of the project) about the implications of this project. It means that the customer gets to ask for whatever they want, without needing to pay more.  If the project isn't time boxed, your boss is giving away unlimited developer time at a fixed price. Make that clear.  If the project is time boxed, explain that changing means redoing and that there's only so much redoing before you run out of time. If he doesn't see this is a problem, **document your time use**.

It's the equivalent of going to a car-repair shop, agreeing a price and then pushing the mechanic to not only fix your airconditioning (the original scope), but also replace your oil, uprate your suspension and do a full engine overhaul. In the long run, expect the customer to be demanding that the car flies, solve world hunger and bring world peace.

***If you're on a billable hours project***, then you're in more trouble. Your boss may not have any incentive for the customer to make reasonable demands, he may just care about you being effectively contracted out to a customer and bringing in revenue.  In that case ***take charge of the project by agreeing an agile methodology with the customer, so you can at least deliver something that will address some customer needs***.   Feel free to take charge, it seems you're the de-facto manager - just make sure you understand what the terms of the contract for this project and work within those boundaries. If the contract is a bad deal, alert your boss, but your company will need to ride it out or renegotiate.

Work in two week sprints, and **show to both your boss and client the ratio of functionality/features delivered vs. overhead (rework) vs other work (training,...).**   It may become clear quite quickly that your project is under resourced, or the demands to high for the price agreed.   Track in spreadsheet, or use a lightweight agile project management tool something like [TargetProcess](http://www.targetprocess.com/)

If the customer is unworkable and your boss only sees you at somebody to pimp out, **reconsider if you want to work in such a place** and if there is any particular reason why you're spending your professional time at your current company over another company.

Keep in mind that you could be in a reasonably strong position to push for some change to improve the situation. If you're the only developer in a non-IT shop, and you quit, your company will struggle to fulfill its obligations to its customer - your boss, lest he's a halfwit, will be mindful of that.  Of course, threating to quit, is the nuclear option, don't play that card lightly.

Comment: You said just what I said, but in better words. Well played ;)

Comment: Well, we're trying to solve the same problem and share the same perspective.  :) You put more emphasis on the hands on stuff, I look at more from a project management angle.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in such situations — and these situations I come across much more than I'd like — is to *demand* a certain minimum. You can only demand something if you have something you can use to pressure your "Boss". In a single-developer-does-all-and-can-do-all situation, your means of pressure is yourself.

There are some countries in the world where employees are badly protected and you have to be careful. For any other country, this almost becomes a no-brainer: simply demand minimum working conditions.

This means: you make a short-list of things you need. Keep it simple. Keep it — almost — free. Don't come with all kinds of procedures. Use a simple bug-tracking system you can also use for planning, report, feature-tracking and new-development (Jira comes to mind). Both your Boss and your Client should be taught to use it. For yourself you probably want to add source control if you don't have it already.

Now comes the tricky part: for a short while, become very strict. Use the comment threads of your tracking system for communication. Your client will continue to call you or e-mail you. Let him. But copy everything to the comment threads and write your answer there. Send the guy a link to the thread as an answer.

You Boss may not like this because he things it will slow things down. Tell him it will become clearer what can and will be done. It will also become clearer where his money (i.e.: your time) went. Tell him that you want to keep an overview yourself, but that it's good for him too. If he's not convinced, tell him to give me a call and then propose to him to do it 100% your way for two months. He'll make it one month and then you have a deal.

It's a tough game out there. But it's doable. Propose a few simple steps towards bettering your environment, communication and tracking. If he refuses, you refuse to do anything more and he'll be stuck with an even worse situation.